# Data binding for Gridcontrol in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, devexpress-wpf

I using `dxg:GridControl` name "grd", and I want to bind data on it, but I can't binding data a column.
I have a `DataTable` for binding on `gridcontrol` :

```
public DataTable GetData()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(DataTable));

            DataTable xdt = new DataTable();
            xdt.Columns.Add("DS", typeof(string));
            DataRow xdr = xdt.NewRow();
            xdr["DS"] = "item1";
            xdt.Rows.Add(xdr);
            DataRow xxdr = xdt.NewRow();
            xxdr["DS"] = "item2";
            xdt.Rows.Add(xxdr);


            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Name"] = "TrieuLe";
            dr["Age"] = xdt; 
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            return dt;
        }
```

I bidding on gridcontrol :

```
private void InitGrid()
        {
            try
            {
                GridColumn col = null;

                col = new GridColumn();
                col.FieldName = "Name";
                col.Header = "Character name";
                col.Width = 50;
                grd.Columns.Add(col);

                col = new GridColumn();
                col.FieldName = "Age";
                col.Header = "X_Age";
                col.EditSettings = new ListBoxEditSettings();
                ((ListBoxEditSettings)col.EditSettings).DisplayMember = "DS";
                ((ListBoxEditSettings)col.EditSettings).ValueMember = "DS";
                col.Width = 50;
                grd.Columns.Add(col);


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

public frm_Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitGrid();
            DataTable xdt = null;
            xdt = GetData();
            grd.ItemsSource = xdt;
        }
```

But data are not binding type `datatable` in column `X_Age`.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is the type of **Age** DataTable?

Comment: I want binding on the listbox on the 1 row of gridcontrol

Comment: Then the type is to be **DataRow** right?

Comment: Apparently you misunderstood my question, I'd binding datatable into the Listbox column

Comment: where you define your binding please look at this - https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6094.